# How to write zip file to disk from byte array

Tags: python, arrays, go, amazon-s3, zip

I'm downloading a zip file from S3 in Go like so:

```
buff := &aws.WriteAtBuffer{}
downloader := s3manager.NewDownloader(session.New(config))
_, err := downloader.Download(buff, &input)
if err != nil {
    log.Println(err)
    return err
}

data := buff.Bytes()
```

I send 'data' to a client that's written in Python3, and need to convert this byte array back to a zip file and put it in a specified directory. I've tried this:

```
file_bytes = msg_obj["Params"]

try:
    zf = zipfile.ZipFile(file_bytes, "r")
    for fileinfo in zf.infolist():
        print(zf.read(fileinfo).decode('ascii'))
except: print("Err:", sys.exc_info()[0])
```

But I get this error:

> OSError: [Errno 36] File name too long"

I just want to 'rebuild' the zip file and save it to a directory.

Comment: are you running your python script on windows? can you provide an example of file name causing the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out how to do this. In go, you'll want to base64 encode it (as a string).

```
buff := &aws.WriteAtBuffer{}
downloader := s3manager.NewDownloader(session.New(config))
_, err := downloader.Download(buff, &input)
if err != nil {
    log.Println(err)
    return err
}

data := b64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(buff.Bytes())
```

Then in python it's as simple as this (where 'file_bytes' is the base64 encoded string):

```
d = base64.b64decode(file_bytes)
f = open('home/update_file', 'wb')
f.write(d)
f.close()
```

And bam, you have a reassembled zip file.

Answer (score 1):

Read [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile), the first parameter of ZipFile class is the file name or file object, not the Zip content.

If you want to read the ZipFile in memory without creating a real file, you'll want to wrap file_bytes using [io.BytesIO](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BytesIO).